# How to propery define nested elements?

Tags: css, sass, susy-sass, susy

Given I have the following markup:

```
<body>
  <article>
    <div class="foo">Foo</div>
    <div class="bar">Bar</div>
  </article>
</body>
```

The `body` has a fixed width of `910px`:

```
body { @include container(910px); }
```

The `body` has an `article` element, which consists of 2 nested `divs` (`.foo` and `.bar`).

At this point, if I wanted `.foo` and `.bar` take up 6 columns each. This is easy enough by doing:

```
article {
  @include container

  .foo { @include span(6 of 12) }
  .bar { @include span(6 of 12) }
}
```

Is it fine for the `body` to `@include container` and the succeeding element (`article`) to contain another `@include container` directly?

In Twitter Bootstrap, a `col` should always follow after a `row`. But this isn't Bootstrap. It's Susy.

In Susy, what is the same concept of a `row` and a `col`? Or does `@include span` basically do both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap uses rows to remove the edge gutters. Susy doesn't use or require rows, so `span()` is all you need. There is also no need for the repeated `container()` mixin. If you want the article to clear floats, you can use a clearfix instead (ours is called `susy-clearfix()`).